# How to mock built-in php socket functions?

Tags: php, sockets, mocking, phpunit

I'm working on some code that reads from a socket, and it goes wrong when it gets a certain large input. I went to add a unit test for this, before fixing it, but got stuck because I cannot mock `fread` (and the other PHP built-in functions I'm using such as `fsockopen`, `feof`, etc.).

In simple terms my problem is that this code fails with "*Fatal error: Cannot redeclare fgets() ...*":

```
function fgets($fp){
return "xxx";
}
```

I realize I could create a socket wrapper class, that my real code uses, and then I could create a mock object for that wrapper class. But that is The Tail Wagging The Dog, and I can think of reasons it is a bad idea, beyond just the principle of the thing. (E.g. Making code more complex, efficiency, having to refactor code not under test yet.)

So, my question is how can I replace the built-in `fgets()` implementation with my own, within a unit test? (Or, if you want to think outside the box, the question can be phrased as: how can I control the string that a call to `fgets($socket)` returns, when `$socket` is the return value from a call to `fsockopen`?)

---

**ASIDE**

Installing apd, as required by the correct answer, is hard work; it was last released in 2004, and does not support php 5.3 out of the box. No Ubuntu package for it and also `pecl install apd` failed. So here are the procedures to install it (these are for ubuntu 10.04) (all done as root):

```
pecl download apd
tar xzf apd-1.0.1.tgz
cd apd-1.0.1
phpize
./configure
# Do edits (see below)
make install
```

See https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=58798 for the patch you need to do. NB. there is only one line you really have to change, so you can do it by hand, as follows: open php_apd.c in a text editor, go to line 967, and replace the `CG(extended_info) = 1` line with this one:

```
CG(compiler_options) |= ZEND_COMPILE_EXTENDED_INFO;
```

Finally, you need to add a php.ini entry to activate it. See http://php.net/manual/en/apd.installation.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have access to APD or Runkit but are using namespaces, try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5337635/664108 (Answer in link refers to time() but it makes no difference)

Comment: Excellent solution - I just did a quick test and it works. I hate to do this to @DragonWok, but this answer is superior so I've decided to move the tick over.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at these:

[bool rename_function ( string $original_name , string $new_name )](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.rename-function.php)

[bool override_function ( string $function_name , string $function_args , string $function_code )](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.override-function.php)

Comment: Thanks; I got as far as confirming this approach works (replacing fgets and feof to supply text from a global array). Getting apd installed on php 5.3 is non-trivial, so I updated my question with instructions on how to do it. (It is amazing it still averages 1000 downloads/month, yet is broken, yet no-one has released a new version in 8 years!)

Answer (score 2):

Change `fsockopen` to `fopen` to do mock, and don't change any other functions.

```
$fp = fsockopen("www.example.com", 80, $errno, $errstr, 30);
```

to

```
$fp = fopen("/path/to/your/dummy_data_file");
```

Comment: Thanks. Still a bit intrusive, but a good approach to minimize the intrusiveness down to a single line.

Answer (score 0):

I [blogged about my experiences](http://darrendev.blogspot.jp/2012/07/mock-socket-in-php.html) which contains full working code showing how to use override_function to achieve the desired goal; both file reading and socket reading. I won't repeat that whole article here, but will just point out how you have to use the functions:

1. Use `rename_function` to give a name to the old, original function, so
   we can find it later.
2. Use `override_function` to define the new behaviour
3. Use `rename_function` to give a dummy name to `__overridden__`

Step 1 is critical if you want to be able to restore the original behaviour afterwards.

In the Food For Thought section at the end I show an alternative approach that I think is more robust, and therefore I think it is safer for replacing file functions when using phpUnit. It creates a permanent function replacement who's default behaviour is to forward to the built-in function. It then checks parameters (the resource `$handle` in this case) to decide if it is being called on a stream we want different behaviour for. (I think you could call this an example of the Chain Of Responsibility design pattern.)