# How to test proxy or socks with php

Tags: php, proxy, socks

For example if I have a proxy or socks:

```
218.36.xx.xxx:88xx
```

How I can write the code so I can test if the socks/proxy is working or not, for example if the

socks work print ok if not print wrong I searched a lot I

didn't find s simple code that explain my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this simple code to test one proxy:

```
<?

$ip   = "192.168.1.1";
$port = "80";
$curl = curl_init();
CURL_SETOPT($curl,CURLOPT_URL,"http://google.fr");
CURL_SETOPT($curl,CURLOPT_PROXY,$ip.":".$port);
CURL_SETOPT($curl,CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE,CURLPROXY_HTTP);
CURL_SETOPT($curl,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,20);
CURL_SETOPT($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,True);
CURL_SETOPT($curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,True);
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

However, if you want to test multiple proxies, use the for loop to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple code by using curl

```
<?
$ip   = "192.168.1.1";
$port = "80";
$curl = curl_init();
CURL_SETOPT($curl,CURLOPT_URL,"http://google.fr");
CURL_SETOPT($curl,CURLOPT_PROXY,$ip.":".$port);
CURL_SETOPT($curl,CURLOPT_PROXYTYPE,CURLPROXY_HTTP);
CURL_SETOPT($curl,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,20);
CURL_SETOPT($curl,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,True);
CURL_SETOPT($curl,CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION,True);
curl_exec($curl);
curl_close($curl);
?>
```

it will test accessing Google from this proxy.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

class ListeningServerStub
{
    protected $client;

```
public function listen()
{
    $sock = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    // Bind the socket to an address/port
    socket_bind($sock, 'localhost', 0) or throw new RuntimeException('Could not bind to address');

    // Start listening for connections
    socket_listen($sock);

    // Accept incoming requests and handle them as child processes.
    $this->client = socket_accept($sock);
}

public function read()
{
    // Read the input from the client &#8211; 1024 bytes
    $input = socket_read($client, 1024);
    return $input;
}
```

}

[How do I unit test socket code with PHPUnit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9136366/how-do-i-unit-test-socket-code-with-phpunit)